# Loading own data for remote training in microsoft azure machine learning

Tags: python, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

So I have been trying to use azure machine learning for faster model training.

I am submitting a training .py file, and within that training file I access my training data, however I am getting error messages regarding that.
I have tried the following code

```
subscription_id = 'my_id'
resource_group = 'my_resource_group'
workspace_name = 'my_workspace'

workspace = Workspace(subscription_id, resource_group, workspace_name)

dataset = Dataset.get_by_name(workspace, name='my-dataset')

with dataset.mount() as mount_context:
    print(os.listdir(mount_context.mount_point))

data = np.load('my-data.npy')
```

But I am getting the error and training failure with the following output logs.

```
  File "train.py", line 29, in <module>
    data = np.load('my-data.npy')
  File "/azureml-envs/azureml_167f4dd4c85f61389bb53e00383dafbe/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 416, in load
    fid = stack.enter_context(open(os_fspath(file), "rb"))
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'my-data.npy'
```

I assume I am incorrectly mounting my dataset on the remote machine, however I am unsure what the correct way to mount it, or submit a training job is?

Answer (score 0):

Did the print statement returns the list of directory correctly?

Here is a sample notebook that shows how to load data in training: https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/tree/master/how-to-use-azureml/work-with-data/datasets-tutorial/scriptrun-with-data-input-output